# legend setting (numpoints and scatterpoints) in matplotlib does not work

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to get the legend right for the dashed line so I played with the rcParams a little bit, but it for some reasons wouldn't work on my computer.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

matplotlib.rcParams['legend.numpoints'] = 5
matplotlib.rcParams['legend.scatterpoints'] = 5


fig, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.plot(range(10), '--k', label="line")
axs.plot(range(10), range(10)[::-1], ':k', label="scatter")
axs.legend(loc=9)

plt.show()
```

And the resultant figure is:
[image: Problematic legend]

And as can be seen, the numpoints for the dashed line is not enough. Would anyone please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make a plot with markers, `matplotlib.rcParams['legend.numpoints']` adjust the number of points drawn on the legend lines.

If you substitute your plot by these:

```
axs.plot(range(10), '--k', label="line", marker='d')
axs.plot(range(10), range(10)[::-1], ':k', label="scatter", marker='o')
```

you get this image:[image]

I don't know what does `matplotlib.rcParams['legend.scatterpoints']` do, but I guess regulates the number of points in the legend of scatter plots.

If you want to change the length of the lines in the legend give a try with `matplotlib.rcParams['legend.handlelength']` and/or `matplotlib.rcParams['legend.handleheight']`. More info about rc file can be found [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html)

As suggested by @tcaswell, you don't have to set rc parameters. All the `legend.*` parameters are available as keywords for the `legend` function. See [`matplotlib.pyplot.legend` documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend)

Comment: `Line2D` objects and `scatter` objects are handled differently by the legend code., `numpoints` sets the number of markers that are shown for `Line2D` objects, `scatterpoints` sets the same for scatter plots.

Comment: and you don't need to use `rcparams` to control this, just pass them as keyword arguments  to `legend`.

Comment: @tcaswell: thank for confirming the `scatterpoints`. later I'll edit the answer adding the fact that you can use `legend` keywords