# Remove line through legend marker with .plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, linechart, line-plot

I have a `matplotlib` plot generated with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

Fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
for i, (mark, color) in enumerate(zip(
    ['s', 'o', 'D', 'v'], ['r', 'g', 'b', 'purple'])):
    ax.plot(i+1, i+1, color=color,
            marker=mark,
            markerfacecolor='None',
            markeredgecolor=color,
            label=i)

ax.set_xlim(0,5)
ax.set_ylim(0,5)
ax.legend()
```

with this as the generated figure:
[image: matplotlib generated figure]

I don't like the lines through the markers in the legend. How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can specify `linestyle='None'` or `linestyle=''` as a keyword argument in the plot command. Also, `ls=` can replace `linestyle=`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, (mark, color) in enumerate(zip(
    ['s', 'o', 'D', 'v'], ['r', 'g', 'b', 'purple'])):
    ax.plot(i+1, i+1, color=color,
            marker=mark,
            markerfacecolor='None',
            markeredgecolor=color,
            linestyle='None',
            label=i)

ax.set_xlim(0, 5)
ax.set_ylim(0, 5)
ax.legend(numpoints=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Since you're only plotting single points, you can't see the line attribute except for in the legend.

Answer (score 9):

You can set the [`rcparams`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) for the plots:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['legend.handlelength'] = 0
matplotlib.rcParams['legend.numpoints'] = 1
```

[image]

All the legend.* parameters are available as keywords if you don't want the setting to apply globally for all plots. See [matplotlib.pyplot.legend](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend) documentation and this related question:

[legend setting (numpoints and scatterpoints) in matplotlib does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528579/legend-setting-numpoints-and-scatterpoints-in-matplotlib-does-not-work)

Answer (score 8):

You should use a scatterplot here

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, (mark, color) in enumerate(zip(
    ['s', 'o', 'D', 'v'], ['r', 'g', 'b', 'purple'])):
    ax.scatter(i+1, i+1, color=color,
            marker=mark,
            facecolors='none',
            label=i)

ax.set_xlim(0, 5)
ax.set_ylim(0, 5)
ax.legend(scatterpoints=1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

To simply remove the lines once the data has been plotted:

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
for h in handles: h.set_linestyle("")
ax.legend(handles, labels)
```