# How do I add a point legend in the matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to make a custom plot using matplotlib. I have got the legends but for the point marker there is a line and white halo around the point. Is there any way where I can add only the point marker by removing the line and halo behind and around the marker?
The script I used is.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

legend_elements = [Line2D([0], [0], color='b', lw=4, label='Line'),
                   Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='w', label='location',
                          markerfacecolor='g', markersize=10),
                   Patch(facecolor='orange', edgecolor='r',
                         label='Color Patch')]

# Create the figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_facecolor('xkcd:black')

ax.legend(handles=legend_elements, loc='center')

plt.show()
```

***Output plot***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try `color='none'`, e.g. `Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='none', label='Scatter',   markerfacecolor='g', markersize=10)`?

Comment: Have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285885/remove-line-through-marker-in-matplotlib-legend).

Comment: @johnC Colour 'none' leaves a black circle around my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add linestyle/ls = '' in 2nd argument of legend_element

#Updated code

> from matplotlib.patches import Patch

> from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
>
> ```
>                 legend_elements = [Line2D([0], [0], color='b', lw=4, label='Line'),
> ```

> ```
>                Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='w', label='location',
>                       markerfacecolor='g', markersize=10, ls = ''),
> ```

> ```
>                Patch(facecolor='orange', edgecolor='r',
>                      label='Color Patch')]
> ```
>
> fig, ax = plt.subplots()
> ax.set_facecolor('xkcd:black')
>
> ax.legend(handles=legend_elements, loc='center')
>
> plt.show()

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VhCE.png)